# Graph-tool: subgraphs as new Graph objects

Tags: python, subgraph, graph-tool

I find graph-tool documentation extremely obscure and much more cryptic than other analogous libraries.

I really can't figure out how to "extract" components (aka connected components) from a graph in graph-tools. I would like to save subgraphs in separate files as separate Graphs but I don't understand how to identify them starting from my Graph object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest (and fastest) way to do this is to do use a GraphView object.

```
# label the components in a property map
c = label_components(g)[0]

# "extract" component number 3
u = GraphView(g, vfilt=c.a == 3)
```

The object `u` is now an induced subgraph of `g` that contains all the vertices of the component label 3. Note that a `GraphView` object does not copy the graph, it simply masks out the other vertices/edges.

If you wish a copy of the subgraph (e.g. if you want to modify it, or the original graph), you just instantiate a new `Graph` object from it:

```
u = Graph(u, prune=True)
```

More information on graph views is available in the documentation: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#graph-views